# struts.serve.static=true and struts,serve.static.browserCache=false not working

Tags: java, struts2

Browser caching using `struts.serve.static=true` and `struts,serve.static.browserCache=false` tags is not working 
I have a requirement when even the user logout and click on back button it is showing welcome screen to avoid this i configured in `Struts.xml`

```
   <constant name="struts.serve.static" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.serve.static.browserCache" value="false" />
```

But still it is not happening finally i tried by placing `struts.serve.static=true` and
`struts,serve.static.browserCache=false` in message resource properties file it is not working could you please help me how to resolve this issue even it is not working

Comment: Your question says you set "serve.static.browserCache" as "false" whereas your code snippet says it is set to true in struts.xml ,What exactly do you want to do ?  If you want to cache the requests , in struts.xml do "<constant name="struts.serve.static.browserCache" value="true" />" else if you dont want to cache have "<constant name="struts.serve.static.browserCache" value="false" />

Comment: @jay <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" /> <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" /> <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" /> <constant name="struts.serve.static" value="true" /> <constant name="struts.serve.static.browserCache" value="false" /> <package name="rju" extends="struts-default,json-default,jfreechart-default" this is the code i have written even it is not working could you please help me

Comment: So that means you don't want to cahce your response .How do you determine if the response is cached ,any specific header /observations  ?

Comment: @jay i mentioned my requirement that back button should not work that is after log out if user click on back button it is showing home screen again with out login .i want to avoid this

Comment: As far as i know the browser back button functionality  is a client side browser thing and cannot be handled by struts 2 . One workaround that might prove useful is to have 
<script type="text/javascript">
history.forward();
</script> 

code present in the header of all pages (which ideally should be a single file/template used throughout application ) .

Answer (score 1):

Above constant will be used by S2 to server the static content from inside the jar and than S2 will write the header to tell the browser to cache the content so that for subsequent request browser need not to fetch the content from the server.This is a standard way to speed up a website and it has nothing to do with browser back button.

When you log-out the user make sure that you invalidate the session.what you are facing is the cached copy of the browser.

When you requesting a copy of page browser checking if the same is with its cache and if yes, in place of requesting the server its serving the content from its cache.Just click on any link which required user to be logged in and you will see that link is not working since in that case browser is requesting the server for the content.

If you want to control this,you can set the cache control headers to request browser not to cache your content something like

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
```

Please go through this thread for details

[how-to-disable-back-button-using-struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497281/how-to-disable-back-button-using-struts2/10497954#10497954)