# logout does not work properly in struts2

Tags: struts2

i am developing a struts project.

In login page action stored username and password in session.

In logout action class using session.invalid and removed that session details and redirected to index page.

But i click back button in browser it goes to the previous page.

Now i need sample code for if i am clicking back button after logging out it will show the error message or it display index page like yahoo mail.

need sample for that in struts2

Comment: You need to instruct the browser not to cache anything (so that, when the back button is pressed, the browser tries to fetch the page again). The blog link provided in this answer tells you how to do that in a neat way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11908343/174184

Answer (score 0):

As I know, very hard to do JS side. because back button belong to web browser. Our project do below way:
When logout, close currently window and open new window. that will help you clear history.